# SpyderKernelApp WARNING No such comm

Tags: python, spyder, genetic-algorithm

Running a GA code on spyder through Anaconda, the script runs till the end and just before running the well plotter ( see below):

```
# Well Plotter
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("ROP Log.pdf")    
plt.figure(figsize=(5,21))
plt.plot(well_proposal['Pred_ROP'] , well_proposal['AHD'], c='r', label= 'Predicted ROP')
plt.ylim( bottom =max(well_proposal['AHD']),  top =min(well_proposal['AHD']))
plt.xlim(right = 100, left = 0)
plt.title('ROP VS Along Hole Depth')
plt.ylabel("Along Hole Depth (m)")
plt.xlabel("ROP (m/hr)")
plt.grid(b= True, which='both')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.tight_layout()
pdf.savefig()
pdf.close()
```

I got the following error " [SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 04cfd510c9b811ea9e48b8e8562fb6fe "

attempt to search for the error but it seems that most of the people stuck with [IPKernelApp] ERROR not [SpyderKernelApp]

Working on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6

Any thoughts on the source of error?

Comment: Im not getting this error on ubuntu 18.04lts, you couod co soder migrating this to mac stack, maybe more amswer rate there. Meanwhile, can you provide detailed steps you took to install on your mac

Comment: Hi there, I am using anaconda package on Mac to run Spyder. This error was not identified on Windows Platforms (similar: Anaconda, Spyder)

Comment: Folks, to elaborate more, I attempt to run in another fresh environment and same error repeated

Comment: Spyder version currently in use on Mac is 4.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem and it was solved by updating TensorFlow. Note: I was using anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

The other issue I came across after installing the above - I did not have enough memory for my data and it started failing again. Upping the accessible memory in the VM fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar '[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: ...' error recently running Spyder through Anaconda. Although I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

In Spyder, try going to Preferences -> IPython Console -> Graphics and switch the graphics backend from 'Automatic' to 'Inline'. This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Hi Psweens, just checked. Graphics Bakend is set as 'Inline' in IPython console. still populating same error

Comment: I have a similar setup - MacoOS catalina - runs well. But am also running Ubuntu on virtual box - has the "no such comm" error. Tried running via interpreter (outside spyder) - the code is killed. Everything is latest/fresh up to date from last Aug 4. Tried Spyder v3x as well - same issue. Very frustrating. Tried different graphics backend

Answer (score 1):

ok - for me the issue has been resolved - needed to add the extended dependencies for QT:

Debian | apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 libxrandr2 libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libxi6 libxtst6
-- | --

as indicated at https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/ :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem:

> Restarting kernel...
>
> [SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm:
> bb97cb82a1fc11eba21c1e00a221a680

you didn't have enough resource ( generally: Memory (RAM) )

[image: check the memory image]

- you should upgrade your resource ( you can use VM )

or

- run your code and try to check "Variable explorer" in your IDE like spyder
  you will find all variables, then remove the largest size after you finish it or save it.

[image: remove your variable image]

You can check your memory by using Activity Monitor to monitor your memory, CPU,...